# Is $\mathrm{arccos}$ of an irrational algebraic number necessarily transcendental?

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry, transcendental-numbers

I know the sine of a non-zero algebraic number is necessarily transcendental; but what about the inverse cosine of an irrational algebraic number?

Comment: @YuriyS Fixed it. I'm just referring to the arccos of an irrational number, not to the cos of the arccos, or to the arccos of the cos, or any other combination of these functions.

Comment: The problem is that the title says a different thing than the text. In the text, you are asking about $\arccos$ of an *algebraic* number, and in the title about $\arccos$ of an *irrational* number. You seem to have forgotten that transcendental numbers are also irrational.

Comment: @user8734617 Changed the text of the question just now; I think it should be clear to everyone now! ^_^

Comment: @YuriyS But isn't $\cos 1$ trascendental?

Comment: :'( I answered the question from the previous, now obsolete, version from the text. The new question is trivial: the answer is no, as pointed before in the comments, because $\arccos(\cos 1)=1$ is algebraic and $\cos 1$ is irrational (and actually transcendental).

Comment: @YuriyS Oh gosh. Please, forgive me. I meant an irrational number that ISN'T also trascendental. I... totally forgot that all trascendental numbers are also irrational, yeah.

Comment: @YuriyS Changed it back to what it said originally, and accepted the answer I got. So... should I ask a new question with the correct text now?

Comment: Please look at the title I made, is this what you wanted to ask?

Comment: @YuriyS Yes, it is! Sorry for the trouble. So, umm... what should I do now? The only answer I've got so far isn't correct anymore, is it?

Comment: Intresting at first glance.

Comment: It is correct. As far as I see it answers precisely your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't the second statement a consequence of the first?

Let $\alpha=\arccos x$, where $x$ is algebraic. However, then $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is also algebraic, as a solution of the quadratic $y^2+x^2-1=0$.

Now, suppose $\alpha$ is algebraic. It follows that either $\sin\alpha=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}=\pm y$ is transcendental - (contradiction), or that $\alpha=0$, which actually gives you one case ($\arccos 1=0$) where $\arccos$ of an algebraic number *is* algebraic. (However, in this case $1$ is not irrational.)

Comment: @YuriyS I know... :'(

Comment: @user8734617 I'm sorry, really. :( My question was about the arccos of an irrational number that ISN'T also trascendental (I've fixed the text now).

Comment: @Labba So we are back to the previous version of the text (hooray!), but then you need to fix the title...

Comment: @user8734617 Please, forgive me for all the trouble. :( So... this means that the arccos of an algebraic irrational number *is* in fact trascendental, right? Since you suppose that $\alpha$ is algebraic and this gets you either a contradiction or the $\arccos 1 = 0$ case...

Comment: @Labba Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: @user8734617 Oh, then I can follow your proof perfectly! Thank you so much, and... sorry for what happened: I didn't stop to think that all trascendental numbers are also irrational when I posted this question.

Comment: @Labba Not a problem at all, glad to help!